# Retrofit Exception

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have integrated the Retrofit library for server calls. I get the below exception when I get a response in retrofit and the app crashes. Unable to understand what's going wrong.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher

Process: com.eclerx_services.android.fs_security, PID: 9495

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.onResponse(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:82)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:140)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

```java
    public LiveData < ClientValidationModel > getEmployeeCompanyExistance(Map < String, Object > params) {
        //isCanceled = false;
        final MutableLiveData < ClientValidationModel > data = new MutableLiveData < > ();
        if (ConnectionManager.Connection(context)) {
            clientValidationModelCall = apiRequest.getEmployeeCompanyExistance(params);
            clientValidationModelCall.enqueue(new Callback < ClientValidationModel > () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call < ClientValidationModel > call, Response < ClientValidationModel > response) {

                    if (!clientValidationModelCall.isCanceled()) {
                        ClientValidationModel clientValidationModel = response.body();
                        if (clientValidationModel != null) {
                            data.setValue(clientValidationModel);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_something_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            data.setValue(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call < ClientValidationModel > call, Throwable t) {

                    if (!clientValidationModelCall.isCanceled()) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        data.setValue(null);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_something_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            data.setValue(null);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

This is the API call & get response function, where it doesn't enter into the `onResponse` callback at all. It is crashing on the `enqueue` call itself.

The API is working fine in Postman and another app as well.

These are the dependencies I am using:

```
// retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.3.1'
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: maybe the library you are using for the okHttp and Retrofit are having a runtime mismatch. can you share the dependencies?

Comment: Added it in the question

Comment: And in build.gradle min sdk is 16

Comment: Try adding this in build.gradle

android {

    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by downgrading the retrofit dependencies from this

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.3.1'
```

to this

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```